# Filter out React warnings caused by components in node_modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Anyone knows a trick for filtering out React warnings in the browser console caused by some node module? They are making things harder to debug and at the moment I can't do anything about it.

Comment: It might be worth posting up the types of warning you are referring to.

Comment: Most of them are for unknown props.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst not being specific to React:

If you are using Chrome there is an option in the console to filter out which messages are shown.  It's the funnel like icon under the Console tab. Then you can choose to filter by Err, Warning, Info, etc...

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I'm familiar with that, unfortunately it doesn't help. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I'm also interested to finding out a way to filter warnings coming from node_modules. @NickDima, did you figure out the solution to it?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to overwrite the logging functions of the `console` object. For example, to filter out "warnings" about the invalid prop type notation that is raised from a package in `node_modules`, you can add this on top of your main `index.jsx` file:

```
const originalConsoleError = console.error;
console.error = (message, ...messageArgs) => {
    // console.log({message, messageArgs}); // uncomment only to see what arguments you receive
    if (
        messageArgs[1] &&
        messageArgs[1].includes("has invalid PropType notation inside")
    ) {
        return;
    }
    originalConsoleError(message, ...messageArgs);
};
```

You can of course perform more complicated checks - uncomment the `console.log` to see what message format arguments you receive.